# Recursive JSON response in Postman of an entity with OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, postman

I have a Client class which contains a list of Cars in a OneToMany relationship. When I try to GET all clients using Postman, the first client will be printed in the response recursively. How can i get the JSON response with the Client and its corresponding car list, without getting the client from the Car response too?

The Car class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String model;
private String color;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Client client;
```

The Client class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

private int age;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "client")
private List<Car> carList;
```

#### Image with the response in Postman

[image: Image with the response in Postman]

Comment: That depends on the Json serialization library you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you use `Jackson` to serialise to JSON , you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to break the cycles:

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Car")
public class Car {

    [.....]
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("carList")
    private Client client;
    [...]
}
```

Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client {

    [....]
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("client")
    private List<Car> carList;
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String model;
private String color;
// Add this annotation
@JSONIgnoreProperties("carList")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Client client;



@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

private int age;

__________________________________________________________________________

// add this annotation also here 
@JSONIgnoreProperties("client")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "client")
private List<Car> carList;
```